# Python freezes after computer sleep/hibernate

Tags: scripting, background, sleep, freeze, pythonw

I have a python script that is running in the background with pythonw. If I close my laptop, it goes into sleep mode. and when I open my laptop, my program has little functionality and freezes after a couple of seconds. Is there any way that my script can tell if my computer is going into sleep mode, so that it can lie dormant and restart when I re-open my laptop?

Comment: Windows Vista SP1 64-bit Python 2.6 compiled in 32-bit mode

Answer (score 0):

You can catch `WM_POWERBROADCAST` window message with `PBT_APMQUERYSUSPEND` event inside it. To catch this message inside Python program, you can create new invisible window and make separate thread repeatedly calling `GetMessage()`.

In the worst case you can archieve all these by using `ctypes` only, but you can also use `pywin32`, sometimes referred to as `win32py`.

Comment: Does this only work with GUI as this python programming is running as a service. Will the same thing work by calling GetMessage() in a thread running within a service?

Comment: @user204088, it depends. You can either enable interactive user for your service, so you will be able to create invisible window directly, but this require console user to be logged on; or use `RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx` and listen for `SERVICE_CONTROL_POWEREVENT` in your `HandlerEx`