# Handling windows suspend event

Tags: python, windows

We have an application running as a service. Currently if the operating system is suspended then the application will crash and not resume correctly. This is really difficult to debug. Is there a way using python to capture an event pre-suspend or hibernate?

Comment: This might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959669/python-freezes-after-computer-sleep-hibernate

Comment: @m170897017 do you know if this works with services?

Comment: No, I didn't give it a try. You can try it by yourself. :)